# Why is everything getting true expect for false in if condition?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Why are all the true, numeric, floats, and strings getting true while checking with if condition, except for false? Examples:

```
puts "Hello World" if 0 # => Hello World
puts "Hello World" if 1 # => Hello World
puts "Hello World" if 2 # => Hello World
puts "Hello World" if 200 # => Hello World
puts "Hello World" if "Ruby" # => Hello World
puts "Hello World" if "Rails" # => Hello World
puts "Hello World" if true # => Hello World

puts "Hello World" if false # => nil
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. It is not the case that everything except `false`  is evaluated as truthy.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362

Comment: @sawa Sorry, Its Typo. Fixed

Comment: From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html): *"... `nil` and `false` are false-values and `true` and any other object are true-values"*

Answer (score 5):

Everything evaluates to `true` in Ruby except `false` and `nil`.

PS: There's no hidden objective here, it's just a language design choice.